# Find most suitable number value x is divisible by

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have an issue which i managed to fix for now, but the fix doesn't work as soon as x changes.

What i need to do.

Get all items from a database (this database is not mine and therefore the data can change at any moment) and fetch the ID of that item.
For each ID i get form this, i need to get data from another source which creates xml output.
Now it creates an array with ID, item buy price, item sell price etc etc etc... and insert on duplicate key updates a table in my own database.

Here's a few restriction I face:
1. The data source from which i get the item price data and such, does not allow for a url longer than 8149 characters.
2. The data source also does not like it, when i make thousands of single item requests (there are 9350 items at the moment, aka 9350 single requests means i will get blacklisted fast).
3. The amount of items could change in future (either less or more).

At this moment, everything is working fine, by doing an if loop($i++) inside a foreach loop over the array of item ID's until I reach 9350 (a set of 50 item id's at a time will be put into the url).
for every 50th item, a function does a curl request with the given url, creating a new xml file with the data on my server, which results in 187 xml files on my server (this works perfectly).

After this, i read out each xml file and dump the data into my own table.

my problem in short:

```
9350 / 50 = 187 (a round number)
```

But as soon as I have 9351 or more items, it is not divisible by 50 anymore (not a round number).

Would anyone have a better idea on how to do this?

details:
item data comes from EVE Online database dump and therefore has a variable amount of ID's.
Item prices come from an url call to eve-central.com/api/marketstat?itemid=xxxxxxx&itemid=xxxxxx&systemid=xxxxxx (with a rough maximum of 60 * itemid=)

EDIT:
The foreach loop.

```
 $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    foreach($itemidarray as $itemid){
        $id = $itemid["itemID"];
        if($i == 50){
            $j++;
            $url .= '&typeid=';
            $url .= "$id";
            $url .= '&usesystem=30000421';
            xmlcreatorfunction($url, $j);
            $i = 0;
        }
        else{
            $url .= '&typeid=';
            $url .= "$id";
            $i++;
        }
    }
```

I hope you can see how this might raise a problem once i have more than 9350 item id's.

Comment: _“But as soon as I have 9351 or more items, it is not divisible by 50 anymore (not a round number).”_ – and _how_ is that a problem?

Comment: Hold on, i will edit the original

Comment: Use [array_chunk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split your array into a multidimensional array with 50 entries in each sub-array (or less in the last one), and then loop over the first dimension, and in that outer loop loop over the second dimension and at the end of the inner loop do something with the data …